# Please Tell me where i am wrong in this Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

emphasized textPlease Tell me where i am wrong
[image]

Requirement Details:

- Account should have two fields of type text area Current Issues(Products), Past Issues(Products)
- Keep count of total issues/Cases at account level, whenever the count reaches 5, send an email to the Account owner to get in touch with the service team.
- When a case is created the total issue count should increase and the Product for which issue is raised should be shown in comma separated format in field Current Issues (Products).
- When a case is closed the product should be removed from current Issues(Products) and should be added to Past Issues(Products) in comma separated format.

```java
Trigger UpdateCaseCount on Case(After Insert, After Update) {
    Set<id> AccIdUpd = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Id> AccPrd = new Map<Id, Id>();
    set<id> ContactId = new set<id>();
 
    //Create a master list to hold the emails we'll send
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =
  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
 
   
    for(Case cs:Trigger.New) {       
        if(Trigger.IsInsert || (cs.IsClosed && Trigger.OldMap.get(cs.Id).IsClosed != cs.IsClosed)) {
            AccIdUpd.add(cs.AccountId);
            AccPrd.put(cs.AccountId, cs.Product__c);
        }
 
    }     

    List<AggregateResult> ARListCurrIssue = [select AccountId, Product__c, Count(Id) CaseCount from Case where
                                             AccountId In:AccIdUpd and IsClosed != True group By AccountId, Product__c];
 
    // Logic to update curernt Issues
    List<Account> UpdAccList = new List<Account>();
    for(AggregateResult AR : ARListCurrIssue) {
        String CurrCount = AR.get('CaseCount') + ', ' +  AccPrd.get((ID)AR.get('Product__c'));
        UpdAccList.add(new Account(Id = (ID)AR.get('AccountId'), CurrentCount__c = CurrCount));
        Integer iCount = Integer.valueOf(AR.get('CaseCount'));
        If(iCount == 5) {
            //write logic to sendMail     
 
            Contact con = [Select firstname,lastname,email,id,name,MobilePhone from Contact where id in :ContactId];
            // Step 1: Create a new Email
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  
            // Step 2: Set list of people who should get the email
            List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
            sendTo.add(con.email);
            mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
  
            // Step 3: Set who the email is sent from
            mail.setReplyTo('lokeshpatil830@gmail.com');
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('lokesh patil');
  
            // (Optional) Set list of people who should be CC'ed
            List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
            ccTo.add('puja.patil@aress.com');
            mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);
 
            // Step 4. Set email contents - you can use variables
            mail.setSubject('Get in touch with the service team');
            String body = 'Dear ' + con.FirstName;
    
            mail.setHtmlBody(body);
  
            // Step 5. Add your email to the master list
            mails.add(mail);
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails);             
   
        }

    } 
    if(UpdAccList.size()>0){
        update UpdAccList;

    }
    // Logic to update Past Issues
    ARListCurrIssue = [select AccountId, Count(Id) CaseCount  from Case where AccountId In:
                                             AccIdUpd and IsClosed = True group By AccountId];
 
    UpdAccList = new List<Account>();
    for(AggregateResult AR : ARListCurrIssue) {
        String PastCount = AR.get('CaseCount') + ', ' +  AccPrd.get((ID)AR.get('AccountId'));
        UpdAccList.add(new Account(Id = (ID)AR.get('AccountId'), PastCount__c = PastCount));
   
    }
   
    if(UpdAccList.size()>0) {
        update UpdAccList;
    }

}
```

Comment: For the curious, line 25 is `String CurrCount = AR.get('CaseCount') + ', ' +  AccPrd.get((ID)AR.get('Product__c'));`

Comment: Why is ID coming as GC1040?  Which line is throwing error here? What is line number 25 in your code above?

Comment: It appears that `Product__c` is not a lookup field.

Comment: Casting of ar.get('Product__c') is returning a string gc1040 which cannot be typecasted to id.